# Destroy a model in loopback.io

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

How can I delete a model in strongloop's loopback.io?

I have seen somewhere command called `persistedModel.destroy()`

but when I exectute `slc persistedModel.destroy()`

I get command not found error.

Comment: Are you trying to delete a model you defined via `slc loopback:model` or delete an instance of model in your database?

Comment: delete complete model defined via slc loopback:model

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Delete `/common/models/your-model.js` and `/common/models/your-model.json`, then delete the lines referencing your model in `/server/model-config.json`.

Comment: Also delete references of relation in other models if relation created.

Comment: hi @superkhau -- I've deleted the reference inside of `model-config.json`, and the model `.js` and `.json` files inside `server/models` (I do not have a `/common/models/`).. but the deleted model is still appearing in the API explorer. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: No, that should be it. Maybe delete your browser cache?

Comment: with apiconnect, we now have some YAML (why not .json, idk). So I assume we need to edit that YAML too, now?

Comment: I hope the loopback team adds this action to their CLI